# How to connect with multiple database in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to connect with multiple databases in Django and to show the selected records from each table in view.

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases) for a guide on how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest to read the respective documentation, to google for tutorials and the like and to attempt your own solution. When you got specific problems, you can post them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django has multiple db support

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
     'NAME': 'dbname',
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
     'USER': 'psqluser',
     'PASSWORD': 'password'
  },
  'users': {
      'NAME': 'dbname1',
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'USER': 'mysqluser',
      'PASSWORD': 'yourpassword'
  }
}
```

You can use migration in following manner

```
./manage.py migrate --database=users
```

You can tell your model to use specific database in following manner

```
class Model:
   name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
   units = models.TextField(max_length=500)

   class Meta:
       app_label = 'users'
```

For more resources you can visit this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: Thank man I'll use your model part with my models.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of creating new connection each time you can connect to server and create an raw query to select data across multiple dbs and create view of required data as below example

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE VIEW vCombinedRecords AS
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.MyTable')
```

the above way is much faster establishing new connection to multiple dbs

cheers!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @riyaj will surely try to implement it.

Comment: @saurabhNema happy coading